# Windows 10 Edge bookmarks not used for Search

Tags: windows, search, bookmarks

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and imported my IE11 bookmarks into the Edge browser. They are all there.

But when I start typing in the (Edge) address bar, or in the Windows search box, it does NOT offer me any Edge bookmarks. It seems as if Search/Edge address bar is not considering them.

Hence I checked my "Indexing Options" settings which in fact only show "Internet Explorer History" besides the directories I configured. Since IE11 uses the Favorites directory I checked if that is included and it was.

However Edge doesn't seem to use it, as I created a new Folder in Edge and it did NOT appear in the Favorites folder. Now I'm at a point where I can see why it doesn't consider my bookmarks, but I don't know how to change it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Edge in Windows 10 (v10.0.10586) no longer stores its favorites as files.  Instead, they are stored in a database.  The old files are still there after the conversion, but they are essentially "abandoned in place"

So, that's why you don't see recent changes... and that's also why the search feature can't find them.

The current builds of Windows 10 still do not support this feature, so it is not likely to appear in the Anniversary Update in July